# Ordered fields that contains all $n^{th}$ roots of all positive elements

Tags: field-theory, real-numbers, radicals

An ordered field that is closed under the operation of taking square roots of all positive elements is called a Euclidean field; given any field $F$, there is a smallest Euclidean field containing $F$, called its Euclidean closure.

What if we want to generalize this notion to consider a field that is closed under the operation of taking all $n$th roots of all positive elements?  That is, suppose $F$ is an ordered field with the property that for all $a>0$ and for every positive integer $n$, the equation $x^n = a$ has a solution.

- Is there a name for such a field?
- Certainly, $\mathbb R$ satisfies this condition; what is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ with this property?  It would seem to be countable, as one can obtain it by beginning with $\mathbb Q$ and adjoining all $n^{th}$ roots.

Comment: The field you're looking for is certainly contained in the real part of the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$, which is countable.  I suspect that they're equal but I don't know that to be the case.

Comment: @RobertShore: They're definitely not equal, since not all polynomials are solvable by radicals!

Comment: Right.  If the Galois group of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q$ isn't solvable, then $\alpha \notin F$.